# Ionic 5 ion-searchbar in header overlapping with status bar in ios

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, statusbar, searchbar, ionic5

In my Ionic 5 application I have a ion-searchbar in the header. It is overlapping with the status bar in ios.

[image]

page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-searchbar clearIcon="close-sharp" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
    debounce="1500" showCancelButton="true" (ionChange)="onSearch()" (ionCancel)="toggleSearch()">
  </ion-searchbar>
</ion-header>
```

I have tried by putting it in `ion-toolbar`. The result is same.

app.component.ts

```
this.statusBar.styleDefault();
```

I have tried `statusBar.overlaysWebView(false)` but is didn't work.

index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated this question has been answered. However what is missing from that answer is that you may need to support both older and newer iOS devices. This is what fixed it for me:

```
 @media(orientation: portrait) {
     ion-content {
      padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top); //ios 11.2
      padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top); //ios 11.1
   }
 }
```